# Is it possible to create a Foreign Key on 2 columns with differing Collations?

Tags: t-sql, foreign-keys, collation

I've tried searching for about an hour through all the Foreign Key / Collation Questions but I can't find something even remotely close to my question.

I have 2 tables from two different software vendors sitting in the same database.  One vendor hard codes their collations to Latin1_General_BIN while the other uses the Database Default (in this case Latin1_General_CI_AS).  Is it possible, without altering any of the columns, to create Foreign Keys between these two Collation Types?

Typically you would simply change one but in this case the Tables are very sensitive and I'm not allowed to make such a change but I have to create a Foreign Key due to a piece of logic in a Trigger that reads data between these two tables only if it finds a Foreign Key:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 
( 
    SELECT name FROM sys.foreign_keys 
    WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID( 'Table1' )
    AND referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID( 'Table2' ) 
)
```

Any help would really be appreciate

P.S. I just can't seem to figure out how this code thing works if anyone would help me out, I put in the 4 required spaces but it's still just displaying my code as text :(

Comment: try extra line breaks before your four spaces and make sure each rw has the spaces (or a single tab works aswell)

Comment: You're such a smarty pants, thanks David, the extra line break did the trick :)   How do you do a Tab? Every time I press tab it knocks the focus to the next control.

Comment: I usually edit my code in notepad++ and then select all of it and press tab once (then I paste it into stackoverflow). That way I can check my syntax for SQL or C# or python or whatever at the same time. You can do the same trick in sql server management studio and probably visual studio aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a foreign key constraint from a field of one collation to a field of another collation can't be done. You will get error message 1757.

Either change the collation of one of the tables or create a work around with a new column that is used instead with the correct collation or create surrogate key columns with integers used for referencing.

If nothing else works and you really really need to fix this type of constraint and performance is not an issue, add a check constraints and/or triggers that will check the referential integrity of data put into the tables. These rules will have to cast all values in one table to the collation of the other in order to compare values so it will be slow and it will be really tricky for you to get use of indexes, proceed with caution.

For example you could have an insert trigger on the referencing table that check if a record with the inserted string exists in the referenced table. Then you would also have to add an update and delete trigger for the referenced table so that it doesn't fall out of range of values that are referenced by records in the referencing table or which cascades updates/deletes. Basically you replicate what foreign keys are and it gets really slow and scales horribly.

Short answer: don't do it, let the tables stay untied or fix the collation of one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the above David, we do use referential integrity triggers on certain tables for very specific instances so I hear what you're saying there.  I also understand the changing of collations as that's what we normally do, but unfortunately, we are not allowed to change the collation of the referencing columns for either of the two tables as they're pivotal to the integrity of each of the two vendors software.  What I do like however, is what you said about possibly adding a surrogate key, though not in it's truest form.  I'll get back to you after I've thrashed out a spec quick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sweet, I think the solution is very elegant.  I'm writing it as an answer purely as it's the full alternative that closest resembles the required solution.  But I'm going to mark your answer as the answer as it's the one that correctly answers my original question.

Right, so first what I did, was I got permission from the vendor who's trigger requires the foreign key, to create a new column in their table as a persisted computed column in the collation of the other vendors table:

```
DECLARE @Collation  nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @SQL        nvarchar(1000)
SET @Collation = ( SELECT collation_name FROM sys.columns WHERE OBJECT_ID IN ( SELECT OBJECT_ID FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'U' AND name = 'Vendor1Table' ) AND name = 'Vendor1Column' )
SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE [Vendor2Table] ADD [Vendor2ComputedColumn] AS [Vendor2Column] COLLATE ' + @Collation + ' PERSISTED'
EXECUTE( @SQL )
GO
```

Next up, I added a candidate key to the computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE [Vendor2Table] ADD CONSTRAINT [CCUNQ1_x] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Vendor2ComputedColumn] ASC
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Then, I simply created the foreign key to the computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Vendor1Table]  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CCFOK01_x] FOREIGN KEY ( [Vendor1Column] )
REFERENCES [dbo].[Vendor2Table] ( [Vendor2ComputedColumn] )
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Vendor1Table] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CCFOK01_x]
GO
```

and finally, the original SQL Script passes with flying colours:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 
( 
    SELECT name FROM sys.foreign_keys 
    WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID( 'Vendor1Table' )
    AND referenced_object_id = OBJECT_ID( 'Vendor2Table' ) 
)
```

Hopefully this small walkthrough helps some other soul some day :)

Thanks for the assist David, appreciate it!